# Decade - "десятилетие" or "десяток"?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, выбор-слова

How does one express **decade** in Russian?

I assume the equivalent words are **десятилетие** and **десяток**, but I'm curious about proper usage.

Some examples...

1) *"It's John and Suzy's 20th anniversary next year."
"Wait, they've been married for almost 2 decades?!"*

2) *Are you a fan of 80s music?*

3) *A decade has passed since I last saw him.*

4) *Michael is in his 50s.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Десятилетие* sounds rather formal and official. It is rarely used in common speech, so it doesn't suit any of your examples.

(1) *Десяток* is preferred, of course

> Wait, they've been married for almost **2 decades**?! --> Погоди, так они женаты уже почти **два десятка** (or simply **двадцать**) лет?!

(2) 50s, 60s, 70s, etc. are naturally translated into *пятидесятые*, *шестидесятые*, *семидесятые* etc. Note that word *года* is silently assumed but rarely spoken here (i.e. *пятидесятые года*)

> Are you a fan of **80s** music? --> Тебе нравится музыка **восьмидесятых**?

(3) If Russian speaker means "about X years", he simply changes word order. So "*ten years*" = "*десять лет*", but "*a decade*" = "*лет десять*". Also note that negative sentence is preferred here.

> **A decade** has passed since I last saw him --> Я его не видел уж **лет десять**

(4) Again *десяток* is normally used if talking about human's age

> Michael is in his **50s** --> Михаил разменял **шестой десяток**